# OpenSSL::SSL::SSLContext::METHODS

Tags: ruby, openssl, ruby-on-rails-6

Recently I upgraded ruby and I would like to know how to solve the following warning on my rails 6 app?

```
gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/le-2.7.6/lib/le/host/http.rb:203: warning: constant OpenSSL::SSL::SSLContext::METHODS is deprecated
```

Thanks

Comment: This is an issue of the le gem which causes this deprecation earning. There is a pull request on their Github repo which might fix this. See https://github.com/rapid7/le_ruby/pull/72

Comment: Thank you! I opted for removing the 'le' gem and the issue has been fixed. Best